# How to give AWS Credentials and config file when program called from service

Tags: python, amazon-s3, service, aws-sdk, boto3

I have developed a python program to upload the file to S3, for that I have configured IAM access values using '`aws config`' command (which creates `~/.aws` folder and `config` and `credentials` with values within it). and when i run my program on the terminal the file uploaded to s3 successfully.

Below is the code fragment:

```
s3client=boto3.client('s3')
s3client.upload_file(FILE_PATH, BUCKET_NAME,FILE_PATH)
```

Now I'm trying to run this program from Linux service, for this i have created new service named `s3upload.service` in `/lib/systemd/system/` folder.

```
[Unit]
Description=Demo S3 upload program
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple 
WorkingDirectory=/home/demouser/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/demouser/s3upload.py
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Surprisingly this doesn't work! Even though i have mentioned working directory for service is `/home/demouser/` it is not recognizing `~/.aws` folder contents?

I'm getting follwing error:

**`NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`**

**Heads Up:**  If I hard code the IAM access values in the program then it's working, but i don't want to follow that approach.

Am i missing anything here when calling as service? how to fix this for service?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say `~/.aws`, you are referring to `/home/demouser/.aws`, correct?

Comment: When you run it from "Linux service", which user is it running as?

Comment: working directory is irrelevant; the creds just have to be in current user's home dir > .aws.

Comment: yes, the credentials stored in /home/demouser/.aws

Comment: Add the `User=` directive and try again.  boto3 api simply clueless about your "WorkingDirectory".

Answer (score 2):

IMO, boto3 api need to read the correct user environment to local ~/.aws.  If you didn't specify the user your Systemd config, the service simply use "root". That's why it failed.

This extra setup should fixed the issue.

```
 [Service]
 User=demouser
```

If you put your python program inside AWS services (e.g. EC2), you can use AssumeRoles for the service, Which you can get rid of the ~/.aws